# Menustrip clicked not showing form

Tags: c#, winforms

```
    private void tsmInventory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Inventory inventory = new Inventory();
        inventory.Show();
    }
```

Hi, I have a problem while displaying the form when user click on the menu strip. I have a form name Inventory, above is my code while i tried with button also cannot, is my method wrong or my forms have problems?

Comment: Do you have attach this handler to click event?

Comment: Are you using a parent MDI form upon which you menu is held?

Comment: Yes I did. Actually i did this with other application with the same method which successfully display other form, I have no idea what's wrong with this

Comment: @Wheels73 sorry i dont get you? I'am new to c# windows form haha

Comment: An MDI form is a container form from which all other forms can be launched and they display within the bounds of the parent mdi form. Does the form that contains the menu strip have the "IsMdiContainer" property set? View the form in designer mode and hit F4 for properties.

Comment: try `inventory.ShowDialog();`

Comment: If you're not using any MDI's etc... check the Start Position property for the form as well. Try center screen, center parent in case it's a focus issue.

Comment: Use breakpoints to check if that event is being fired.